# Inspecting drop down menus in new Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm on Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m (newest), and this update is messed up. They put it, when you have inspector open, that any DOM change will flash with purple on the changed element (like in Firefox), but now I cannot inspect any hovered object (also like in FF, which is why I don't like to use it when doing front end developing).

I'm talking about js triggered events, like superfish for instance. Before, I could hover the menu, and cover the menu with the inspector, and the menu would stay opened, and I could go in the inspector see what pseudoelements are created, change the paddings and such directly, and see the change. Now, when I hover the menu, and right click to inspect it, the menu closes, and I cannot inspect it!

I tried dragging the inspector over, but nothing helped. This new 'feature' is annoying as hell. Is there a way to inspect js triggered events, without putting break points on elements (which works, but is kinda pain in the ass)?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Hover over the element with your mouse and press F8 (this will only work in Chrome) to pause the script execution. The hover state will remain in visible to you. If you're on a Mac, you may have to open system preferences and check off "Use all F1,F2,etc" check box (Or simply use fn + F8).

*Sometimes it only works if you are in the Sources tab of the inspector.*

*Yes, you should be in the source tab and **MOST IMPORTANT is you should close all the opened tabs in the Sources tab before you press F8(win) or Fn+F8(mac)**. *

Comment: I think they fixed this issue in the meantime. I can add a break point, I know that, but the easier solution is to hover over, bring the inspector and fiddle in the inspector while the hover is active, and the whole site isn't frozen.

Comment: On Mac you can just press fn+F8, while your inspector is open on Sources tab

Comment: Lately, after pressing `F8`, the hover first disappears **and then** stops the execution. It's incredibly frustrating, don't know why this happens.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious, but I had to on the 'sources' tab for this to work. OSX and chrome (74.0.3729.157)

Comment: If the shortcut doesn't work even with the Sources tab open, just click the "Pause" button directly in the sources tab

Comment: works for me, you gotta use sources tab though, well it's obvious!

Comment: This answer doesn't work for all cases.  We need a new solution that will work for all cases.

Comment: This worked for me with React-Select but only if I turned on "Emulate a focused page" first in the dev tools settings.

Answer (score 201):

Depending on the menu element type, I ran into this issue with drop-down input menus. The reason it's disappearing when I inspect it, is because a `blur` or `focusout` event is always triggered on the element when I click anywhere outside the element.

One way I was able to inspect the element is to prevent these events from being triggered is by removing their event listeners:

- Inspect the input element on Chrome
- Go to the Event Listeners tab and remove the `blur` or `focusout` event
  [image]

Once the event listeners are removed, you can open the menu and inspect it without disappearing

Comment: That might work for input elements. I just tried for a select element, it still disappears

Comment: Sometimes input can also bind to `focusout` event instead of `blur`. In some cases deletes focusout is what works for me

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. We need to upvote this so it is the better answer!

Answer (score 98):

In Chrome, press F12 to open the developer console, then click on Settings (cogwheel icon) or press F1:

[image: Dev tools Settings]

then find & check the "Emulate a focused page" option.

[image: Check Emulate a Focused Page Option]

Update: as noted in comments, this option is now in another place. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64456947/1440076) answer.

Comment: thank you, this is the simplest and easiest answer so far

Comment: This is imo the correct answer. Took ages to find, and saved so much torture, this is rare as gold.

Comment: This is the best answer without any hacks. Pure gold

Comment: This was the easiest option but seems like it is removed from Chrome version 86 onwards :(

Comment: Why would they remove it lol! Its just too great

Comment: It's still there, just moved to a different place: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64456947/1440076

Comment: Yes, moved to a different place. No, this option doesn't work for holding the select open.

Comment: @asiop I activate it via the cmd palette (ctrl + shift + p), which is quicker IMO

Answer (score 27):

Adding to ["In Chrome, press F12 to open the developer console, then click on Settings (cogwheel icon) or press F1:"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56975705/1581050) above;

In Chrome 86 and above you can find "Emulate a focused page" option here:

DevTools >> Elements >> "Kebab" menu (3 vertical dots by the settings cog) >> More tools >> Rendering.

Alternately: With Devtools open: Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command menu HUD, enter "emulate a fo" to narrow the search results and enter (or click) to toggle the setting.

Comment: Hello Ben, welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for contributing! This answer looks like a useful addition to an existing answer. Could you edit the previous answer to include this detail, and then delete this answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

On Mac, you can press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to pause the script after having opened the dropdown. You can then use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to inspect elements.

Comment: Fantastic!   Note: you do have to be on the Sources tab in the dev tools first.   Otherwise when you press cmd-\ the hover closes as it takes you there.

Answer (score 18):

Only way that would work for me was doing `setTimeout(() => { debugger }, 3000)` in the console and opening the dropdown while timeout was running.

Pressing pause button in dev tools UI or F8 key to pause script execution would both close the menu.

Comment: Genius!! I had to disable Self-XSS warning first though: DevTools > Gear icon > Experiment > Uncheck: Show warning about Self-XSS

Answer (score 10):

> Now, when I hover the menu, and right click to inspect it, the menu
>   closes, and I cannot inspect it!

I faced the same issue and what I used was **Expand recursively** option on chrome dev tools:

The steps are:

1. Inspect the dropdown field
2. Find the dynamic DOM (the purple highlight)
3. Right-mouse click on that dynamic DOM
4. Choose **Expand recursively**: 
   [image]
5. We can see all elements are there

Here is a demo:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**In Firefox**

In Inspector, right click on a node that contains the dropdown, select:

Break on... > Subtree modification

This will pause execution the moment dropdown is... well... dropped down.

Answer (score 8):

I just used emulate a focused page and it worked like a charm

1. go to settings
2. go to more tools
3. find Rendering
4. find "emulate a focused page" and click the radio button

voala  now you can inspect your select element

Comment: I once used this option, but forgot, and was searching for long time. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can set an interval that writes out the content of a given element in the JS console every second. Drop this in the console and open the dropdown.

```
setInterval(() => 
    console.log(document.querySelector('.Select-menu-outer').outerHTML),
1000)
```

Comment: Perfect for react-select

Answer (score 2):

in my case i do following steps

- Open **developer tool** or **inspect** page
- click three dot button at top right

[image]

- click on **More tools** -> **Rendering**

[image]

- then check on  **Emulate a focused page** option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not very fancy but you can write this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    debugger
}, 3000)
```

Then you have 3 seconds to open the dropdown and then you can inspect the elements. This is nice because works in any browser

Answer (score 1):

None of the above referred remedies worked for me.
As our drop down (React based) will close on any single click (right or left)
So we found out the below workaround:

- In Chrome  Open developer tools
- first click on the drop-down in collapsed state & let it expand with options
- then under the element section, right-click on the div node (make sure not to left click before right clicking), which contains details of the drop-down items
- Then select option '**Expand Recursively**'
- Then required details were shown
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the CSS Editor in Chrome to apply a state, for instance, the state of 'hover'.

In the Developer Tools, you select an element. On the right hand you have a square with an arrow over it. Click that and you can choose a state. For instance, pick hovered and you'll see both your window and your CSS update as if the element is being hovered right now.

Comment: Yeah, but that will only trigger the css state you manually put as `element:hover`, or `element:active` or `element:focus`. My change is js based. A plugin will add a class, and changes style (like superfish does for instance). So state toggle won't help here...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, press F12 first, at the page with the menu, then point your mouse to the element menu (the menu will drop down), then press CTRL + Shift + C. Now you can inspect all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found, was just to right click before clicking on the inspect button.