# Emulate a focused Page option not available in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

There used to be an option, "Emulate a focused page," under "Global preferences" in Chrome developer tools. However, I am not able to find that option anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 81):

There are two ways to invoke it now:

- A checkbox in `Rendering` panel

  [image]
- Command panel:

  1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
  2. type `emfo` to find the `Emulate a focused page` item
  3. press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I don't have that "rendering" tab in current Chrome 86/Windows 10. Where is it?

Comment: Use the commands palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) or the devtools own three-dot menu to show it.

Comment: On a Mac the shortcut ended up being ⌘-Shift-P for me

Comment: This only works if you keep the F12 window open, as in other settings.

Comment: This worked the best for me when you want to inspect the elements without it closing.

Answer (score 10):

The `Emulate a focused page` is in the "Rendering Panel".

Some people don't see the "Rendering Panel" in recent versions of Chrome.

As of **May 2023**, the menu item to enable the "Rendering Panel" is shown in the screenshot below.  After the "Rendering Panel" is opened, "Emulate a focused page" is the 9th checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must navigate to the Rendering panel to access "Emulate a focused page"

**Steps to open the Rendering panel:**

1. Open Chrome developer tools
2. Click the vertical three dots in the top right corner
3. Select "More Tools" from the dropdown menu
4. Select "Rendering" from the dropdown menu
5. Select the "Emulate a focused page" checkbox that appears in the panel