# Is it possible to emulate focused page in Firefox like it is in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, lost-focus

I don't think Firefox has any options to `emulate a focused page` to debug then what happens once a tab loses focus, [like Chrome can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456886/emulate-a-focused-page-option-not-available-in-chrome-developer-tools).

Is there any way to fixate the focus state of a window in Firefox? (Like a settings option hidden somewhere) It seems that whatever can be done via JS/Webconsole will be overridden by the browser once the tab actually loses focus.

One can, of course, debug the script through various other ways (using break points, calling the function that listens to the onblur event, etc.), but this Chrome option is very handy and I wanted to know if something similar can be done in Firefox, viz. to fix the focus state of the tab.