# Inspect vue-multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, web-inspector, vue-multiselect

I want to inspect vue-multiselect dropdown (see eg: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-select-with-search).
[image]

I tried to pause the script as described here: [Inspecting drop down menus in new Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386116/inspecting-drop-down-menus-in-new-chrome), but I always have it closed so I cannot inspect it.

[image]

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to turn on the 'Emulate a focused page' feature? It is talked about briefly in the link you provided, but I find that this works really well. I can enable it, have dev tools open, then when I click the multiselect open, I can then explore the DOM and the mulitselect doesn't close.

Check out https://tinytip.co/tips/devtools-focused-page/ for more specific details about how to use this feature.

Hope this helps